# Is Wiktionary right that 女奴 meant "cat" in the distant past?

Tags: meaning

[Wiktionary for 女奴](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A5%B3%E5%A5%B4):

> (archaic) cat

I tried looking up it up in other dictionaries, but it's so old that I can't find any other dictionaries that list it?

Comment: That's why it is listed as "archaic". This definition has no place in modern Chinese

Answer (score 2):

First time heard of it, but I did find it in a few dictionaries.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you find some copies of the books and stuff they're quoting?

Comment: @Malady The dictionaries only give one same quote from Tang Dynasty, 張泌 《妝樓記》. There's a copy of the book from wikimedia: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:%E5%8F%A2%E6%9B%B8%E9%9B%86%E6%88%90%E6%96%B0%E7%B7%A8083.pdf

Comment: I would ask where in the book it comes from, but it's 788 pages long, so I won't?
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a7/%E5%8F%A2%E6%9B%B8%E9%9B%86%E6%88%90%E6%96%B0%E7%B7%A8083.pdf

Answer (score 0):

edited.

following lilysirius’ answer, i deleted previous comment

“cat” was termed as “貓”, “猫”, or “狸奴” in the past.

in the zen koan “南泉斬貓”, there’re verses:

> 南泉因東西兩堂各爭**猫**兒。師遇之。白眾曰。道得即救取**猫**兒。道不得即斬却也。眾無對。師便斬之。趙州自外歸。師舉前語示之。州乃脫草履安頭上而出。師曰。汝適來若在。即救得**猫**兒也。　頌曰。

> 手把**狸奴**定死生。禪人空使口相爭。趙州救得成何事。恰似天明打五更。

> 提起兩堂應盡見。拈刀要取活**狸奴**。可憐皮下皆無血。直得橫屍滿道途。

> 盡力提持只一刀。**狸奴**從此脫皮毛。血流滿地成狼籍。暗為春風染小桃。

http://tripitaka.cbeta.org/mobile/index.php?index=X65n1295_011